# git filter-branch chmod

Tags: git, unix, chmod, git-filter-branch

I accidental had my umask set incorrectly for the past few months and somehow didn't notice.

One of my git repositories has many files marked as executable that should be just 644. This repo has one main master branch, and about 4 private feature branches (that I keep rebased on top of the master).

I've corrected the files in my master branch by running `find -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` and committing the changes. I then rebased my feature branches onto master.

The problem is there are newly created files in the feature branches that are only in that branch, so they weren't corrected by my massive chmod commit. I didn't want to create a new commit for each feature branch that does the same thing as the commit I made on master. So I decided it would be best to go back through to each commit where a file was made and set the permissions.

This is what I tried:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'chmod 644 `git show --diff-filter=ACR --pretty="format:" --name-only $GIT_COMMIT`; git add .' master..
```

It looked like this worked, but upon further inspection I noticed that the every commit after a commit containing a new file with the proper permissions of 644 would actually revert the change with something like:

```
diff --git a b
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I think I must be mis-understanding how `git filter-branch` works.

### My Solution

I've managed to fix my problem using this command:

```
 git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'FILES="$FILES "`git show --diff-filter=ACMR --pretty="format:" --name-only $GIT_COMMIT`; chmod 644 $FILES; true' development..
```

I keep adding onto the `FILES` variable to ensure that in each commit any file created at some point has the proper mode.

**However**, I'm still not sure I really understand why git tracks the file mode for *each* commit. I had though that since I had fixed the mode of the file when it was first created that it would stay that mode unless one of my other commits explicit changed it to something else. That did not appear to the be the case.

The reason I thought that this would work is from my understanding of `rebase`. If I go back to `HEAD~5` and change a line of code, that change is propagated through, it doesn't just get changed back in `HEAD~4`.

Comment: `filter-branch` is not `rebase`. `filter-branch` with a tree-filter just changes the tree in each commit. `rebase` replays the changes introduced by each rebased commit. I'm not sure what you were expecting with filter-branch.

Comment: @CharlesBailey My understanding of `fitler-branch --tree-filter` is that during the process, if any changes are made to the working directory then that change will cause a new commit to be made. Child commits then MUST be replayed ontop of it. So why does it not act like rebase?

Comment: Yes, with a tree filter all changes are made _to the commit being altered_. Then the tree is reset to the state of the next commit. If the file was original executable in the next commit then it will be executable in the tree. Unless you specifically remove the executable in the filter then it will stay executable. By using `git show` to determine the list of files you were only removing the executable bit in commits where the file was originally touched. In commits where the file wasn't touched you weren't removing the executable bit.

Answer (score 2):

You are only changing the mode of files in commits where they where changed because you are generating the the list of files with `diff`. In commits where they weren't originally changed they will retain there original mode. E.g. something like:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git ls-files -z | xargs -0 chmod -x' master
```

Comment: For the rev-list I'm passing `master..` since It only affects commits on my private feature branch. But it isn't working. I'm getting `error: .gitignore: does not exist and --remove not passed`

Comment: It seems like `update-index` expects the file to exist in the working tree. Using `--tree-filter` works. But filter branch finishes with `Ref '...' is unchanged`

Comment: @EvanPurkhiser: Sorry, you're right, let me update my answer.

Comment: I've solved the problem, but I don't have a clear understanding of my solution. Check my updated question. Would love some insight!